# Notifying Others On Provisioning Failure Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We currently use a functional ID to order the machines primarily through the API. Is there a way to notify others when an order cannot be provisioned and a ticket is opened from Softlayers end against the functional ID? I noticed the `message` data type in the product order

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order

but I don't think that would work. Someone suggested the master of the account has to make the change. Is there a way to add the ability to notify others through the order JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nowdays that's not possible, because the notification are sent to master user's email, you can submit a ticket for this requirement if you like.

In case of tickets, you can attach mails for notifications, but it works when a ticket is already created, I belived that this is not exactly what are you looking for, but this is the only way to add notification in tickets.

- [SoftLayer_Ticket::addAttachedAdditionalEmails](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/addAttachedAdditionalEmails)

I believe that one workaround could be to set a rule for forwarding in the master account email's inbox